# Match a particular word along with one word before and one word after, when each of them are separated by a delimiter in postgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql

I want to match match a particular word along with a leading word and a trailing word using regex. The match should be done with a condition that the left word and right word are different form the one in the middle.

If i have few lines as below.

```
 1. apple,banana,orange,banana
 2. orange,banana,guava
 3. banana,orange,banana,orange,apple,guava
 4. guava,apple,orange,orange,banana
```

**Required Output**
If *orange* is a taken as middle word then, the output I'm looking for is as below:

```
1. (banana,orange,banana)
2. (orange,banana)
3. (banana,orange,banana), (banana,orange,apple)
4. (apple,orange,banana)
```

Currently, I have the following regex

```
([\w\-\(\) ]+)?,?(orange)+,?([\w\-\(\) ]+)?
```

which is giving me the following

```
1. (banana,orange,banana)
2. (orange,banana)
3. (banana,orange,banana), (NULL,orange,apple)
4. (apple,orange,orange)
```

I have already spent a day on this, please help me with this problem. Thanks!

Comment: did you try look around regex? I will not capture characters.

Comment: Without a regex it would be much simpler...